# Having a hard time understanding how to use nubBy

Tags: haskell

I have a problem where i have to manipulate a list of a list of floats. [[Float]]. these list of floats are of length 4.  I want to remove duplicates where the first 3 elements are tested, but ignore the 4th one.  This is the last part of a multi part problem and i have been banging my head on a wall for a while figuring out how to use this.  I cant find any helpful information.

```
fixDuplicates :: [[Float]] -> [[Float]]
fixDuplcates [[]] = [[]]
fixDuplicates x = nubBy ?
```

Comment: Of topic comment: If the 4th number is special, perhaps you should reify it somehow when defining the datatypes? Kind of how one would use a struct w/ meaningful names to store a record instead of using an array of values.

Comment: the datatypes are predefined and i have to work with what im given

Comment: You could create a conversion function then ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nubBy` takes a function to use for comparing elements for equality. Your definition of equality is that two lists are equal if their first three elements match. A straightforward implementation of this is:

```
fixDuplicates xs = nubBy firstThreeMatch xs
   where firstThreeMatch ys zs = take 3 ys == take 3 zs
```

Comment: Could drop the repetition and become `nubBy ((==) \`on\` take 3)` with an additional import of `Data.Function`.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much, my program works perfectly now.